# Obtaining of the username over REST API with one step

Tags: rest-api, salesforce-id

I want to get user name from SF over REST API. Is it possible to do with only one step when I have access token. As I saw from documentation and samples I have first to call something like this

> https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/User/
>   headers : Authorization: Bearer access_token

then I get user URL, something like this :

> url:/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/User/005i0000000awMl788

and finally when I invoke that link over REST API I will get username. Is it possible to do this with one step when I have access token ? It is not natural for me to make two calls for such information.

Thanks,
Rastko

Comment: I think is NOT possible using REST on only one request. Take a look of this sample: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11748/636

Answer (score 1):

assuming you know

- Userid and OrgId
- or you have the Id URL

you could call the OAuth identity service

https://login.salesforce.com/ORG_ID/USER_ID

have a look here
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Comment: Yes, I know that I can get username directly if I have Userid and OrgId pair. I'm having to get UserId with access token when I get response form SF. I have described that in this case : [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12409/how-do-i-get-the-user-details-when-authenticating-with-oauth-2-0)

Comment: Isn't the access token based on the password? Can't see a way to insert that in the URL